# $\int |f(x)|^p dx = -\int_0^{\infty} t^pd\mu(t)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I want to show that if $f\in L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and
\begin{equation}
\mu(t):=\{x:|f(x)|>t\},
\end{equation}
then
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f(x)|^pdx = -\int_0^{\infty} t^pd\mu(t).
\end{equation}
I really am clueless as to what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m$ be the Lebesgue measure and define a measure $\nu$ on the Borel sigma algebra by $\nu (E)=m(f^{-1}(E))$. Then $\int gd\nu =\int g(f(x))dx$ when $g =I_E$ (by deifnition). It follows that the equation $\int gd\nu=\int g(f(x))dx$ holds for any simple function $g$, hence for any non-negative measurable function $g$ (by Monotone Convergence Theorem). Take $g(t)=|t|^{p}$ to finish the proof. [$\int gd\nu=-\int g d\mu$].

Comment: Thank you. BTW, where do I pick up the factor of $-1$?

Comment: @user134070 You have defined $\mu (t)$ to be  the measure of $\{f: f(x) >t\}$. If you take the measure of $\{f: f(x) \leq t\}$ you will not get the negative sign.